# Prove that if $$ is a graph that $|  () | ≥ |  () | +4$ then $$ contains at least two disjoint edge cycles.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $$ is a graph that $|  () | ≥ |  () | +4$ then $$ contains at least two disjoint edge cycles.

I have no idea about this question!
Please help me to prove it.

Comment: What is an edge round?

Comment: @Arjuna196 round is enough and I should delete the edge!

Comment: What do you mean by edge round? Can you give a definition? It is very unclear.

Comment: From the context, it looks like 'separate rounds' means disjoint edge cycles.

Comment: Hint: you can do casework and reduce this to the case when all vertices have degree 3 or more.

Comment: You're right.My English is weak and this has become a big problem!Now I corrected the question.Is this OK?@MishaLavrov

Comment: Yes, this is better.

Comment: What is an "edge cycle"? Do you mean "edge-disjoint cycles", i.e., two cycles having no edge in common, although they may have vertices in common?